# Row as XML in SP

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

From SP i need to get a row as as XML (Includeing all fileds.) Is there any way we can get like below.

```
Declare @xmlMsg varchar(4000)
select * into #tempTable from 
dbo.order for xml raw 

select @xmlMsg = 1 from #tempTable 

print '@xmlMsg' + @xmlMsg
```

Row i would like to get it as XML output.

Answer (score 0):

select @var = (Select * from table for XmL raw)